# How to move back to a previous typo in ispell?

Tags: ispell

When running `M-x ispell`, is it possible to go back to the previous typo? For example, I accidentally pass a typo and want to go back to it.

Comment: If you use flyspell, `flyspell-auto-correct-previous-word` will do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can temporary exit from `ispell` (not kill it) just hitting arrow keys. Then you can edit as you like or move back before the previous typo. To resume ispell just type `M-x ispell-continue`. to re-enter a second time ispell just type `M-x` and `up arrow` (to list the command history).
This is not a perfect replacement of the functionality you asked for but I used several time and it is enough for my requirements.

Comment: the keyboard shortcut for M-x ispell-continue is: C-u M-$

Answer (score 2):

No, `ispell` just works in batch mode AFAICT.

I recommend using the built-in `flyspell`.  This will give you on-the-fly feedback and provide commands like `flyspell-check-next-higlighted-word` and `flyspell-check-previous-highlighted-word` to jump around.

Comment: I see `flyspell-check-previous-higlighted-word` but not `flyspell-check-next-higlighted-word` on Emacs 28.1. Did they remove it?